# What do you call these cord-like shapes at the end of the tool?

Tags: word-request

[image]

I am thinking they have a name, but I can't even think of a proper word to describe them. I am not asking what the tool is the tool is a pimple squeezer, but I am asking what the things at both ends are. You can see them enlarged too on the picture above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d say that it has metal **loops**. That’s what [another pimple remover](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004UO67OU) describes them as in its instructions:

> Place the thin wire loop end on the area and press down firmly.

(Plus, there is a similar looking tool used in pottery that is called a [loop tool](https://www.bigceramicstore.com/tools-supplies/tools-supplies/ribbon-tools.html).)