# Is there an adjective that means something is going out of the body at one end and going back in at the other end?

Tags: word-request

[image: tool for removing pimples]

Is there an adjective that means something is going out of the body at one end and going back in at the other end? I know I [used the same picture not long ago](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/221883/9161), but now I am looking for an adjective to describe the shape. The best phrase I came up with is "hollow convex shape", but that doesn't really says much, because the thing at the end has a "cord-like structure" and one end goes out of the body and the other goes back in right beside it. Is there an adjective for this?

Comment: yes, I think you might want to edit your question to substitute another word for "the body": maybe "an object", "a structure", or even "*a* body". "*The* body" often implies a *human* body, and it makes your question sound a little gross.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **exact answer** to your written question (I cannot open the image) is,

**closed-loop** [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/closed-loop) adjective; of or relating to a processing system in which effluents are recycled, that is, treated and returned for reuse.

**dialysis** could be associated with this, but you can have dialysis without it being directly returned into the body.

However, I am unsure that **what you asked was what you meant to ask?**